# How to move a field left and right without user input, using ints in xna

Tags: xna, c#

Well I have this code:
Variables:

```
int x;
int maxX = 284;
//Rectangle
Rectangle sourceRect;
//Texture
Texture2D texture;
```

In the `Update()` method:

```
if (x++ >= maxX)
{
   x--; //To fix this x -= 284;
}
```

And the `Draw()` method:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(263 + x, 554), sourceRect, Color.White, 0f, origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0); //I have some properties which are not important
```

So what I want is to move the field horizontaly with these ints, but it moves to the right to from point 1 to point 2 and blinks back to point 1 and so on here's the desired output:

```
[        OUTPUT:        ]
[                       ]
[<1>FIELD            <2>]
[                       ]
```

So the field is at point 1. I want it to move to point 2, like this:

```
[<1>FIELD---------------><2>]
```

And then, when it reaches point 2:

```
[<1><---------------FIELD<2>]
```

And loop like this. From point 1 to point 2 and then to point 1 and point 2 again. The total distance between the points is 284 pixels (points are part of background image). I know it's about decrementing the integer but how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to explain but I think you want to have the point move right until it hits the max point, then start moving left until it hits the min point.

one solution would be to add a direction bool e.g.

```
bool movingRight = true;
int minX = 263;
```

Update()

```
if( movingRight )
{
    if( x+1 > maxX )
    {
        movingRight = false;
        x--;
    }
    else
        x++;
}
else
{
    if( x-1 < minX )
    {
        movingRight = true;
        x++;
    }
    else
        x--;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since this is XNA, you have access to a GameTime object inside your update method. With that and Sin you can do what you want very simple.

```
...
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        var halfMaxX = maxX / 2;
        var amplitude = halfMaxX; // how much it moves from side to side.
        var frequency = 10; // how fast it moves from side to side.
        x = halfMaxX + Math.Sin(gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds * frequency) * amplitude;
    }
...
```

No need for branching logic to make something move from side to side. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can work with a movement factor, this way you avoid to keep an state, that will become harder to maintain when other movements are added.

```
 int speed = 1;

 void Update() { 
     x += speed;
     if (x < minX || x>MaxX) { speed =-speed; }
     x = (int) MathHelper.Clamp(x, minx, maxx);
 }
```

Comment: I get error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'.", however if you edit this so it works for me I would be very thankfull.

Comment: I have added the int cast, though you will end using float for controlling the speed ;)